# How do I remember which way round PRIOR should go in CONNECT BY queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a terrible memory. Whenever I do a CONNECT BY query in Oracle - and I do mean *every* time - I have to think hard and usually through trial and error work out on which argument the PRIOR should go.

I don't know why I don't remember - but I don't.

Does anyone have a handy memory mnemonic so I always remember ?

For example:

To go **down** a tree from a node - obviously I had to look this up :) - you do something like:

```
select
    *
from
    node
connect by
    prior node_id = parent_node_id
start with
    node_id = 1
```

So - I start with a `node_id` of 1 (the top of the branch) and the query looks for all nodes where the `parent_node_id` = 1 and then iterates down to the bottom of the tree.

To go **up** the tree the prior goes on the parent:

```
select
    *
from
    node
connect by
    node_id = prior parent_node_id
start with
    node_id = 10
```

So starting somewhere down a branch (`node_id = 10` in this case) Oracle first gets all nodes where the `parent_node_id` is the same as the one for which `node_id` is 10.

**EDIT**: I **still** get this wrong so thought I'd add a clarifying edit to expand on the accepted answer - here's how I remember it now:

```
select
    *
from
    node
connect by
    prior node_id = parent_node_id
start with
    node_id = 1
```

The 'english language' version of this SQL I now read as...

> In NODE, starting with the row in
>   which `node_id = 1`, the next row
>   selected has its `parent_node_id`
>   equal to `node_id` from the previous
>   (prior) row.

**EDIT**: Quassnoi makes a great point - the order you write the SQL makes things a lot easier.

```
select
    *
from
    node
start with
    node_id = 1
connect by
    parent_node_id = prior node_id
```

This feels a lot clearer to me - the "start with" gives the first row selected and the "connect by" gives the next row(s) - in this case the children of node_id = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the order in which the records are going to be selected: the link-back column on each record must match the link-forward column on the PRIOR record selected.

Answer (score 5):

I always try to put the expressions in `JOIN`'s in the following order:

```
joined.column = leading.column
```

This query:

```
SELECT  t.value, d.name
FROM    transactions t
JOIN
        dimensions d
ON      d.id = t.dimension
```

can be treated either like "for each transaction, find the corresponding dimension name", or "for each dimension, find all corresponding transaction values".

So, if I search for a given transaction, I put the expressions in the following order:

```
SELECT  t.value, d.name
FROM    transactions t
JOIN
        dimensions d
ON      d.id = t.dimension
WHERE   t.id = :myid
```

, and if I search for a dimension, then:

```
SELECT  t.value, d.name
FROM    dimensions d
JOIN
        transactions t
ON      t.dimension = d.id
WHERE   d.id = :otherid
```

Ther former query will most probably use index scans first on `(t.id)`, then on (`d.id`), while the latter one will use index scans first on `(d.id)`, then on `(t.dimension)`, and you can easily see it in the query itself: the searched fields are at left.

The driving and driven tables may be not so obvious in a `JOIN`, but it's as clear as a bell for a `CONNECT BY` query: the `PRIOR` row is driving, the non-`PRIOR` is driven.

That's why this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    hierarchy
START WITH
        id = :root
CONNECT BY
        parent = PRIOR id
```

means "find all rows whose `parent` is a given `id`". This query builds a hierarchy.

This can be treated like this:

```
connect_by(row) {
  add_to_rowset(row);

  /* parent = PRIOR id */
  /* PRIOR id is an rvalue */
  index_on_parent.searchKey = row->id;

  foreach child_row in index_on_parent.search {
    connect_by(child_row);
  }
}
```

And this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    hierarchy
START WITH
        id = :leaf
CONNECT BY
        id = PRIOR parent
```

means "find the rows whose `id` is a given `parent`". This query builds an ancestry chain.

**Always put `PRIOR` in the right part of the expression.**

**Think of `PRIOR column` as of a constant all your rows will be searched for.**

Comment: I like "Always put PRIOR in the right part of the expression" - it does make it easier. Also putting "start with" at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason that this is difficult to visualise each time, is because sometimes the data is modelled as `id` + `child_id`, and sometimes it is modelled as `id` + `parent_id`.  Depending on which way round your data is modelled, you have to place your `PRIOR` keyword on the the opposite side.

The trick I find, is always to look at the world through the eyes of the leaf-node of the tree you're trying to build.

So (speaking as the leaf node) when I look up, I see my parent node, which I may also refer to as the `PRIOR` node.  Ergo, my `ID` is the same as his `CHILD_ID`.  So in this case `PRIOR child_id = id`.

When the data is modelled the other way around (i.e. when I hold my parent's ID rather than him holding mine), my `parent_id` is the same value as his `id`.  Ergo in this scenario `PRIOR id = parent_id`.