# Will swapping the operands of = in a LEFT OUTER JOIN predicate make any difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables A and B and there is a left outer join between them.

```
A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.CODE
```

Will swapping the left and right operands of `=` in the ON condition ...

```
A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.CODE = A.ID
```

... change anything performance wise or return different set of rows?

Comment: This is the right duplicate; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785583/does-the-order-of-tables-referenced-in-the-on-clause-of-the-join-matter

Comment: Probably this is indeed a duplicate, but not of the question designated.  That one is about the order of the *tables* in a join.  This one is about swapping the left and right operands of `=` in a join predicate.  Of course, exchanging the left and right operands of `=` makes no difference, neither in a join predicate nor elsewhere.

Comment: This question is slightly different than the linked duplicate. The duplicate linked relates to JOIN order, not ON order.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: no, the question is an exact duplicate. But the accepted answer is only answering it at the end: _"As for the order in the comparison, it doesn't matter in any RDBMS, AFAIK."_

Comment: All the optimization the query optimizer does and you think the order of the = can make a difference.    A = B  versus B = A is the same evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Will reversing the ON condition return a different set of rows? No.

Will reversing the ON condition change performance? It shouldn't, but it might. Any difference in performance would be negligible.